# How to integrate Sencha Mobile with Drupal?

Tags: drupal, mobile, sencha-touch, extjs

I would like to integrate Drupal pages with Sencha Mobile. How to do that? Maybe with usage of Services Module? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

There are three Drupal groups that are discussing the subject, they would be your best starting point:

[Sencha Touch UI for Drupal](http://groups.drupal.org/node/84094)
[Drupal 7 and Sencha Touch](http://groups.drupal.org/node/103244)
[Sencha Touch UI](http://groups.drupal.org/sencha-touch-ui)

As far as I know there's no solid release available yet though.

Comment: Thank you, but there is no solution for that now as I see. Sencha mobile is only for Webkit with poor support for Gecko.

Comment: @clive are you are the best

Answer (score 0):

There is also a very good and interesting presentation: [Mobile Drupal with Sencha Touch](http://travistidwell.com/presentations/drupal-sencha/#/).